# $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure iff $f_n-f$ converges to $0$ in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> Prove that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure iff $f_n-f$ converges to $0$ in measure.

What I know:

$(f_n)$ is said to converge in measure to $f$ if:

$$m\{|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon\}<\epsilon \text{ for all } n\geq N$$

where $m(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

I'm not sure where to start for the forward direction.

For the backwards direction:

Suppose $f_n-f$ converges to $0$ in measure. Then $m\{(f_n-f)-0\geq \epsilon\}<\epsilon$, which just simplifies to $m\{f_n-f\geq \epsilon\}<\epsilon$.

I'm new to the concept of convergence in measure so a hint would be preferred over a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Your definition of convergence in measure is not correctly stated : $f_n \to f$ in measure if for every $\delta >0$, $\lim _n \mu( |f-f_n|>\delta ) =0$. You just have to write the (correct) definition of convergence in measure to show the result.

Comment: @Patissot I think these two definitions are equivalent. I mean, we don't need independent $\delta,\epsilon$ in the definition.

Comment: The post has been editing since. The definition seems to be very unclear to the author of the post, that's why I wrote a complete definition with universal quantification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in measure, i.e., for every $\epsilon >0$

\begin{equation}\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\mu\{|f_n-f|>\epsilon\}=0.
\end{equation} 
In particular, 
\begin{equation}\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\mu\{|(f_n-f)-0|>\epsilon\}=0,
\end{equation} which says that $f_n-f$ converges to $0$ in measure.